# Mysql busquedas con LIKE no reporta registros con acentos

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy haciendo un autocomplete on php, MYSQL y JQUERY. Lo hice adaptándolo a partir de un tutorial.
El código me funciona y me auto completa un select pero si el registro, (es una tabla con campo nombres ,campo apellido), en alguno de sus campos tiene un acento, una ñ, etc no me lo muestra en el select.

La tabla está cotejada en UTF_general_ci.

Soy bastante inexperto y se me escapa. Si me pudieran al menos encauzar en la posible solución a les estaría agradecido.

Aquí les pongo el código php que busca los resultados.

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'term' ] ) ) {
 include( 'dbcontroller.php' );
 $db_handle = new DBController();
 $return_arr = array();
 $sqlc = "SELECT  cl_nombre, cl_apellidos, id_cl FROM car_cliente WHERE cl_apellidos  like '%" . $_GET[ 'term' ] . "%'   ";
 $faq = $db_handle->runQuery( $sqlc );
foreach ( $faq as $k => $v ) {
    /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
    $row_array[ 'value' ] = $faq[ $k ][ 'cl_apellidos' ];
    $row_array[ 'cl_apellidos' ] = $faq[ $k ][ 'cl_apellidos' ];
    $row_array[ 'idx' ] = $faq[ $k ][ 'id_cl' ];
    $row_array[ 'cl_nombre' ] = $faq[ $k ][ 'cl_nombre' ];
   array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
  }
 echo json_encode( $return_arr );
}
?>
```

Y este es el script

```js
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();        
j(function() {
j("#curso").autocomplete({
  source: "getApellidos.php",
  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      j('#curso').val(ui.item.cl_apellidos);
      $('#idx').val(ui.item.idx);
      $('#nombres').val(ui.item.cl_nombre);
      $('#apellidos').val(ui.item.cl_apellidos);
 $("#curso").focus();
   }
});
});
```

```html
                   <form>

   <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="username">
                          <label for="ComprobarUsuario">Nombres para el ejemplo: <strong>Carlos</strong>, <strong>Camila</strong>, <strong>Candy</strong>, <strong>Carina</strong></label>
                          <input autofocus class="form-control input-medium ui-autocomplete-input" value=""  autocomplete="off" id="curso" name="curso" type="text">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
   <table class="table">
                      <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">#</th>
                          <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                          <th scope="col">Nombres</th>
                          <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row"><input readonly class="caja" value="" id="idx" type="text"></th>
                          <td><input readonly class="caja" value="" id="apellidos" type="text"></td>
                          <td><input readonly class="caja" value="" id="nombres" type="text"></td>
                          <td><input readonly class="caja" value="" id="apellidos" type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

```
Edito y pongo estructura de base de datos

    -- Versión de PHP: 7.4.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `calendar`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `car_cliente`
--

CREATE TABLE `car_cliente` (
  `id_cl` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `cl_nombre` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `cl_apellidos` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `car_cliente`
--
```

Muchas gracias

Edito.
Resuelto gracias a vuestra ayuda en los comentarios y especialmente de A.Cedano.
El problema era la codificación en la conexión a la base de datos.

Añandiendo a la función

$this->conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');

Así queda la conexión al completo:

```
 <?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "";
    private $user = "";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "";
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
        $this->conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    }
    
    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }
    
    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
    function insertQuery($query) {
        mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
        return $insert_id;
    }
    
    function getIds($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row[0];
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
   function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: el like no debe ser en mayúscula, puedes dejar una muestra de la base de datos, estructura??????

Comment: Gracias por responder. El like está en minúscula, ¿Quieres decir que debe estar en mayúsculas?

Comment: El `like` funciona igual en mayúsculas o minúsculas. Si ejecutas la sentencia directamente en MySQL no funciona?

Comment: Si la ejecuto directamente en la base de datos SÍ que me muestra el registro con ñ, con acentos, etc

Comment: Si dices que en la BD funciona, entonces el problema debe ser de codificación en el contexto: revisa que estés asignado `utf8` tanto en el HTML, en el objeto de conexión y en la configuración de PHP. Considera también limpiar los datos con `TRIM`, ante posibles espacios en blanco y demás.

Comment: Muchas gracias. A.Cedano. He asignado a la conexión UTF8 y ya me reconoce todos los apellidos. Muchas gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando trabajamos con conexiones a base de datos y queremos que la comunicación entre servicios en este ejemplo php y mysql utilicen un contexto igualado de acentos se debe declarar alguna propiedades:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "test");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Conjunto de caracteres inicial: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());

/* cambiar el conjunto de caracteres a utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Conjunto de caracteres actual: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

de esta manera: `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` cambiara el conjunto de caracteres de trabajo.

**tambien existe la version para:**

```
php <= 5.6 
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

**driver PDO:**

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

También es importante que el archivo con extensión `.php` este guardado como `UTF-8 sin BOM`

**Documentación:**

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php

**Ejemplos:**

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco.

Comment: Hola @ManuelRisco! Si te ha servido la respuesta de Francisco, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo le recomenpensará  por su ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)

Comment: Gracias. Perdón por la inexperiencia con la votación de comentarios. Hecho. Tomo nota y leo.